# Desktop not working after removing unity 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome

in ubuntu 11.10 on a macbook pro 7.1 i just removed unity and installed back gnome, everything is working perfectly but the desktop. Looks like i can't right-click on it, (while i can on panels and menu), not even with `ctrl+alt+right-click` and if i `$touch something`, it creates something but it does not appear in desktop view ( the one with background ).

It's not fundamental but would be nice :)
Thanks

ps: I know it's probably a common issue and I searched but its rather difficult to find something, since all keywords refers also to gnome-desktop, and install only related issues are shown :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Comment: I get lots off error text when trying this : `dconf-WARNING : failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --authlautnch=...'` < same with sudo

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of Gnome 3. You can't right click on or put files/shortcuts on the desktop. It's supposed to be less cluttered/distracting. Quickly googling the issue will find you some [tutorials](http://json8.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/enabling-desktop-icons-in-gnome-3/) on how to enable that functionality.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, voted Bal since answer was quicker.